# Mastering a foreign language without staying in a country to which the language is native

Tags: language

I am not a native English speaker. What I would like to understand is - if a non native speaker who’s got a fairly decent command on the language (in this case say English) speaks to his or her kid in English, would it increase their kids grasp on English and the ability to comprehend the language better. In essence, does interacting with kids in a foreign language increase the kid’s grasp on a foreign language? I understand accent, pronunciation, modulation, intonation all these aspects play an important role but my question is primarily about the usage, and by that I mean the usage of words, grammar, phrases, idioms.

I would like to add one more parameter, If the family is not resident in a native English speaking country, and in future if the kid travels to an English speaking country would they be able to seamlessly integrate into the English speaking community (nothing to do with cultural values, in this context), and would their ability to comprehend, read, write and speak be as good OR nearly as good as the native speakers. Have you come across such cases wherein someone mastered a foreign language even without staying in the country to which the language is native?

Comment: [Also relevant](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/3824/420).

Comment: Another user recently [mentioned in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13582753#13582753) that _it takes at least 20% of the child's waking hours in a given week of hearing a second language spoken fluently to even get the child conversational,_ so even a good non-native English speaker would have to be very consistent.

Comment: Welcome to the community.  Torben and Beofett's actions on your post are a kind gesture to show you where you can find the answers to your question.  I know when I was new, things were a bit confusing, but it's nice when people give us a bump in the right direction.  Hope to see you strongly active in the future!